# Notation of UML class diagram

Tags: c++, uml, class-diagram

I have the following classes:

```
class cManipulator : public cEditor
{
 public:
    cManipulator( ICanvas *canvas, cCompositeRoot* obj );
    ~cManipulator();
 private:
    ....
    class VisitorSetProp* m_SetVisitor;
    class VisitorGetProp* m_GetVisitor;
}

cManipulator::cManipulator( ICanvas* canvas, cCompositeRoot* obj ) :
...
{
...
    m_SetVisitor = new VisitorSetProp (this);
    m_GetVisitor = new VisitorGetProp (this);
}

cManipulator::~cManipulator()
{
    delete m_SetVisitor;
    delete m_GetVisitor;
}

class VisitorSetProp : public Visitor
{
public:
......
}

class VisitorGetProp : public Visitor
{
public:
....
}
```

What the variant on UML class diagram is right?

[image]

or

[image]

Comment: Edited to clarify title. **Not** the same as OP's earlier question with the same title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **first one is right** (named *composition*), since the `cManipulator` has the lifetime responsibility for `m_SetVisitor` and `m_GetVisitor`.

The second one is named *aggregation*. It's used when more then one object point to the visitors, and they are not resposible for the lifetime.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

The first one is the correct one!
`Visitor` is the abstract class which is implemented by `VisitorSetprop` & `VisitorGetprop`.
`VisitorSetprop` & `VisitorGetprop` are also related to `cManipulator` through composition.
All these relations are appropriately shown in the first diagram.

Answer (score 1):

In this instance, I believe the first would be appropriate notation for two reasons:

1. The messages move in one direction (unidirectional). In other words, the cManipulator is the only one to know about the relationship and any function calls made are going from the cManipulator class to the other one.
2. When you delete an instance of this class, it must remove those two instances of that class (another class presumably does not have access to those classes). Even if you don't destruct them properly, it still should be true that no other class has those pointers.

See here: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/content/RationalEdge/sep04/bell/

Answer (score 0):

The right one is your source Code. There is no such a Righ or Wrong model...All models are WRONG.
But some of them are useful for the problem at the hand.

```
The model is Wrong if it does not help you to solve or make easy any of your problems.
```

P.S. : Actually source code is also not the right model:-)